# numpy.absolute() whit array type input data

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to convert an array of complex numbers to its corresponding `numpy.absolute()` value.
The task seems easy but I'm getting an error while storing the result into an output array.

The source array is ok, and looks like:

```
print(Impedance)
Out: [(0.0007800000603310764+0.0014299999456852674j), (0.0008200000156648457+0.001509999972768128j)]
```

When I print:

```
print(np.absolute(Impedance)) 
Out: [1.62889531e-03 1.71828401e-03]
```

So far so good, but I note that in the second output there are no commas in the array representation.... I've read through different forum questions that this can be related to the way `numpy` represents arrays..... I'm a Python 'roockie' so I just assume that this is the way it is ....

The issue comes when I try to store the output into an Array:

```
Imped_AngD  = float(np.angle(Impedance,deg=True))   # angle in degrees
```

Then I get the following error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

any clues¿?¿?
Thanks in advance

Eneko

Comment: I made an error while posting, I represented the np.angle function whereas I meant np.absolute, but in any case the result (and the error...) that I'm having is the same.

Comment: Remove the `float()`, why did you add that?

Comment: Python lists are printed with commas.  Numpy arrays are not printed with commas.  They are not the same.

Comment: Great, solved. Thanks for your feedback. Most appreciated.